# Floyd-Warshall Path Reconstruction

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, graph

Below is the implementation for the Floyd-Warshall algorithm, which finds all-pairs shortest paths for a given weighted graph.

The function `floyd_warshall` takes a graph as an input, which is represented by an edge list in the form of [*source*, *destination*, *weight*]

The `path_reconstruction` function outputs the shortest paths from each vertex that is connected to every other vertex.

Please provide suggestions for improvements of any sort.

```
import sys

INF = sys.maxsize

def floyd_warshall(graph):
    source_vertices = [column[0] for column in graph]
    destination_vertices = [column[1] for column in graph]
    vertices = list(set(source_vertices) | set(destination_vertices))

    distance = [[INF] * len(vertices) for i in range(len(vertices))]
    next_vertices  = [[0]   * len(vertices) for i in range(len(vertices))]

    for i in range(len(vertices)):
        distance[i][i] = 0
    for source, destination, weight in graph:
        distance[source-1][destination-1] = weight
        next_vertices[source-1][destination-1] = destination-1

    for k in range(len(vertices)):
        for i in range(len(vertices)):
            for j in range(len(vertices)):
                if distance[i][j] > distance[i][k] + distance[k][j]:
                    distance[i][j] = distance[i][k] + distance[k][j]
                    next_vertices[i][j]  = next_vertices[i][k]

    path_reconstruction(distance, next_vertices)

def path_reconstruction(dist, nxt):
    print("Edge \t\t Distance \t Shortest Path")
    for i in range(len(dist)):
        for j in range(len(dist)):
            if i != j:
                path = [i]
                while path[-1] != j:
                    path.append(nxt[path[-1]][j])
                print("(%d, %d) \t\t %2d \t\t %s"
                      % (i + 1, j + 1, dist[i][j], ' - '.join(str(p + 1) for p in path)))
    print()

def main():
    edge_list1 = [
        [1, 3, -2],
        [2, 1, 4],
        [2, 3, 3],
        [3, 4, 2],
        [4, 2, -1]
    ]
    edge_list2 = [
        [1, 2, 10],
        [1, 3, 20],
        [1, 4, 30],
        [2, 6, 7],
        [3, 6, 5],
        [4, 5, 10],
        [5, 1, 2],
        [5, 6, 4],
        [6, 2, 5],
        [6, 3, 7],
        [6, 5, 6]
    ]

    floyd_warshall(edge_list1)
    floyd_warshall(edge_list2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[FMc](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/248584/100620) has made some excellent points.  I'll try not to repeat those.

## Vertices

You determine the list of vertices using:

```
    source_vertices = [column[0] for column in graph]
    destination_vertices = [column[1] for column in graph]
    vertices = list(set(source_vertices) | set(destination_vertices))
```

and then repeatedly use `len(vertices)` through-out your code.

FMc suggests using:

```
    vertices = set(col[i] for col in graph for i in (0, 1))
    n = len(vertices)
```

Both implementations use sets to form a cover of all vertices.  But this doesn't really make any sense.  You're using `range(len(vertices))` to determine the indices.  What if the graphs used the vertices 1, 2, 4, & 5?  Your sets would be `{1, 2, 4, 5}`, the length of the set is `4`, and `range(4)` produces the indices `0`, `1`, `2`, and `3`.  But you execute:

```
    for source, destination, weight in graph:
        distance[source-1][destination-1] = weight
```

you'd find `source` or `destination` is `5`, compute subtract 1, to get the index 4, and find you've fallen off the end of the matrix!

Clearly, there is a requirement that all indices from `1` to `N` must be used, with no gaps allowed.  But then, you don't need a set.  You just need to find the maximum index.

```
    n = max(edge[col] for edge in graph for col in (0, 1))
```

## Indexing is slow

In this code, for 100 vertices, how many times is `distance[i]` evaluated?  How about `distance[k]`?

```
    for k in range(len(vertices)):
        for i in range(len(vertices)):
            for j in range(len(vertices)):
                if distance[i][j] > distance[i][k] + distance[k][j]:
                    distance[i][j] = distance[i][k] + distance[k][j]
                    next_vertices[i][j]  = next_vertices[i][k]
```

`distance[i]` is looked up somewhere between 2000000 and 4000000 times?  Seems excessive, perhaps?  `distance[k]` is looked up between 1000000 and 2000000 times.  A wee bit less, but still quite a few.

Once you've entered the first `for` loop `k` is a constant for that iteration.  You could lookup `distance[k]` once.  Similarly, once you've entered the second `for` loop, `i` is a constant for that iteration.  You could lookup `distance[i]` once.

```
    for k in range(len(vertices)):
        distance_k = distance[k]
        for i in range(len(vertices)):
            distance_i = distance[i]
            for j in range(len(vertices)):
                if distance_i[j] > distance_i[k] + distance_k[j]:
                    distance_i[j] = distance_i[k] + distance_k[j]
                    next_vertices[i][j]  = next_vertices[i][k]
```

Now, were looking up distance[k] only 100 times, and distance[i] only 10000 times.  This will be a speed improvement.

We can do the for loops better: getting the indices and looking up the values together, using `enumerate`, and looping over the rows of the `distance` matrix:

```
    for k, distance_k in enumerate(distance):
        for i, distance_i in enumerate(distance):
            for j in range(len(vertices)):
                if distance_i[j] > distance_i[k] + distance_k[j]:
                    distance_i[j] = distance_i[k] + distance_k[j]
                    next_vertices[i][j]  = next_vertices[i][k]
```

Again, `distance_i[k]` does not change in the inner loop, so we can look it up once in the middle loop:

```
    for k, distance_k in enumerate(distance):
        for i, distance_i in enumerate(distance):
            dist_ik = distance_i[k]
            for j in range(len(vertices)):
                dist_ik_kj = dist_ik + distance_k[j]
                if distance_i[j] > dist_ik_kj:
                    distance_i[j] = dist_ik_kj 
                    next_vertices[i][j]  = next_vertices[i][k]
```

Finally, we can iterate over the `distance_k` row of the matrix, to avoid addition lookup overheads:

```
    for k, distance_k in enumerate(distance):
        for i, distance_i in enumerate(distance):
            dist_ik = distance_i[k]
            for j, dist_kj in enumerate(distance_k):
                dist_ik_kj = dist_ik + dist_kj
                if distance_i[j] > dist_ik_kj:
                    distance_i[j] = dist_ik_kj 
                    next_vertices[i][j]  = next_vertices[i][k]
```

Both `next_vertices[i]` and `next_vertices[i][k]` are constant in the inner loop; we could look them up once in the middle loop, for additional savings.  You could even `zip` `distance` and `next_vertices` together in the `for i, ...` statement and look up both `distance_i` and `next_vertices_i` simultaneously.  But perhaps that is getting a little too advanced.

## Memory

Python lists are memory hogs.  This doesn't matter if your graphs don't have more than a few hundred vertices.  But if you want to support larger graphs (thousands of vertices? hundreds of thousands of vertices?), you'll want to use memory efficient structures.

You could use `numpy` to create your NxN `distance` and `next_vertices` matrices.  But if you don't have `numpy` installed, we don't have to use that sledgehammer.  Python does come with more memory efficient `array` objects, which can only store scalar information (integers, floats, characters) instead of the Jack-of-all-Trade heterogeneous lists of lists.

`next_vertices` hold integer vertex values.  Instead of:

```
next_vertices  = [[0]   * len(vertices) for i in range(len(vertices))]
```

consider:

```
zeros = [0] * len(vertices)
next_vertices = [array.array('I', zeros) for _ in range(len(vertices))]
```

The rest of the code wouldn't need to change.  You still access the data like `next_vertices[i][j]`.

This creates a `list` of `array` integers, where the array takes a mere 2 bytes per value, instead of 8 bytes per element, plus the storage requirement of each integer (around 28 bytes each).

You can do something similar for the `distance` matrix.  But now we need to know: are the weights always integer values, or are they floating point?  You might want to use the the `'d'` type code, if weights can be fractional.  See the [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#module-array) for details.

Comment: Another point: when constructing the `distance` matrix, you should not use `INF = sys.maxsize`. That was valid in python 2 but not in 3. It is not guaranteed to return the largest int size. Try replacing `INF`  with `float('inf')` instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604966/maximum-and-minimum-values-for-ints

Comment: @Joe A good point.  Good enough that it should be it's own independent answer that you can gain reputation from, instead of a comment where you don't.   But `math.inf` is preferable to `float('inf')`.

Comment: @Joe I went through the link and `sys.maxsize` is valid in python 3, and `sys.maxint` is valid in python 2. Since I'm on python3.x, I used the former. Strongly agree on `math.inf`.

Comment: @Saurabh you're right I was thinking of `sys.maxint`. Still a good practice to use `float('inf')`.

Answer (score 6):

Your program provides a good example for seeing how one can increase code readability through some common techniques: (1) convenience variables to avoid verbose repetition; (2) code organized as small commented "paragraphs" or blocks; and (3) the use of **shorter** variables names to lighten the visual weight of the code, thus enhancing ease of reading and visual scanning. Note that short names must be used judiciously: because they can be cryptic, short vars typically
derive their meaning either from a consistently used convention in the program
or from other contextual clues (eg, from nearby functions or collections having more explicit names and from well-placed comments). Here's a heavily edited version of `floyd_warshall()` along those lines. Because I'm lazy, I will assume that you implemented Floyd-Warshall correctly.

```
def floyd_warshall(graph):
    # Collect all vertices.
    vertices = set(
        col[i]
        for col in graph
        for i in (0, 1)
    )
    n = len(vertices)
    rng = range(n)

    # Initialize the distance and next-vertex matrix.
    dists = [
        [0 if i == j else INF for j in rng]
        for i in rng
    ]
    next_vertices = [
        [0 for j in rng]
        for i in rng
    ]

    # Populate the matrixes.
    for src, dst, weight in graph:
        i = src - 1
        j = dst - 1
        dists[i][j] = weight
        next_vertices[i][j] = j

    # Do that Floyd-Warshall thing.
    for k in rng:
        for i in rng:
            for j in rng:
                ikj = dists[i][k] + dists[k][j]
                if dists[i][j] > ikj:
                    dists[i][j] = ikj
                    next_vertices[i][j]  = next_vertices[i][k]

    return path_reconstruction(dists, next_vertices)
```

A bigger issue is that your `floyd_warshall()` function should not be calling a
function that prints. Rather it should return some kind of meaningful data.
That approach makes your function more readily testable. For example,
`path_reconstruction()` could return a list of declarative dicts.

```
def path_reconstruction(dists, next_vertices):
    # Same ideas here: return data, don't print; use convenience
    # vars where they help with readability.
    rng = range(len(dists))
    paths = []
    for i in rng:
        for j in rng:
            if i != j:
                path = [i]
                while path[-1] != j:
                    path.append(next_vertices[path[-1]][j])
                paths.append(dict(
                    i = i,
                    j = j,
                    dist = dists[i][j],
                    path = path,
                ))
    return paths
```

Then do your printing outside of the algorithmic code.

```
def main():
    edge_lists = [
        [
            [1, 3, -2],
            [2, 1, 4],
            [2, 3, 3],
            [3, 4, 2],
            [4, 2, -1],
        ],
        [
            [1, 2, 10],
            [1, 3, 20],
            [1, 4, 30],
            [2, 6, 7],
            [3, 6, 5],
            [4, 5, 10],
            [5, 1, 2],
            [5, 6, 4],
            [6, 2, 5],
            [6, 3, 7],
            [6, 5, 6],
        ],
    ]
    for el in edge_lists:
        paths = floyd_warshall(el)
        for p in paths:
            print(p)
```

Comment: In python 3 ‘range’ is an iterator, so rng will be exhausted after the first use.

Comment: @MaartenFabré Try it in a Python REPL and I think you'll be surprised. For example: `rng = range(3) ; print(list(rng)) ; print(list(rng)) ; print(rng[1])`. Or `next(rng)`, which will fail, because a range is not an iterator. There's probably a more authoritative way to prove the point, but those practical usages convince me.

Comment: @MaartenFabré A `range()` is an iterable, not an iterator.  It is reusable in exactly the same way a `list` is reusable; you can iterate over them multiple times, even simultaneously in parallel threads.

Comment: :facepalm:  that's what you get by replying on your phone without checking...